# CharArray as Field modify the request data input

Tags: android, json, kotlin, jackson, retrofit2

**Background :**

- Retrofit version : 2.5.0
- RxJava version : 2.2.0

**Code snippet :**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("enroll/device")
fun token(@Field("username") username: String, @Field("password") password: CharArray): Single<Token>

private val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper))
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)

        retrofitBuilder.build()
    }
```

**Logs**

> login=merchant1&password=1&password=2&password=3&password=4&password=o&password=4&password=A&password=%26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what work for me, I Changed from `FormUrlEncoded` to `@Body` :

```
@POST("enroll/device")
fun token(@Body credentials: Credentials): Single<Token>
```

And I defined the *data class* as follow :

```
data class Credentials(@JsonProperty("login") var login: String,
                          @JsonProperty("password") var password: CharArray)
```